# What RAID policies should be used for a XenServer host?

Tags: dell, dell-poweredge, xenserver, raid10, dell-perc

I have a server with a PERC6/i card and a RAID-10 array running XenServer 6.1 with 6x VMs, one of which is SBS 2008 and the rest are a mix of file server, video-on-demand and SQL database server.

The current read/write/cache policies are as follows:

```
No Read Ahead
Write Back
Disk Cache Disabled
```

Read performance is really poor compared to write performance and I wondered if changing these settings would improve overall system performance? If so, which ones would you suggest changing?

By changing the RAID policy, does this mean the RAID array has to be created from scratch?

Comment: You should definitely have some Read Ahead, how much is likely going to be a 'trial and error' situation.

Comment: Changing the policy doesn't require the RAID array to be recreated.